# Problem installing j2re-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin on 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64

Tags: java, linux, installation, xen

i got a little problem when i try to install the j2re on my linux-xen.... it tell me this:

```
./j2re-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin: line 383: ./install.sfx.5488: No such file or directory.
```

Ive checked out some forums and nothing... anyone has any idea?¿

Thanks

Comment: This is all exit when i tried to exec the .bin



Unpacking...
Checksumming...
0
0
Extracting...
./j2re-1_4_2_19-linux-i586.bin: line 383: ./install.sfx.5488: No existe el fichero o el directorio
Done.

Comment: Can't you use a package manager to install j2re?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks job for the comment, the problem was that my virtual machine was a amd64 architecture, and for that i cant install that type of j2re. I have changed the architecture to i386 and everything works fine.

Bugs